# Codigo PHP aveces muestra informacion y aveces no

Tags: php, php7, php8

Tengo 2 semanas con el siguiente problema, tengo un archivo PHP con mas de 2mil líneas de código, resulta que aveces muestra información y aveces no, solo por probar coloqué en el encabezado un **print** y luego un **exit**.

```
print "HOLA";
exit;
```

Al abrir la pagina en el navegador muestra el mensaje "HOLA", luego actualizo con F5 y ya no muestra nada, luego de actualizar como 5 veces aproximadamente entonces vuelve a mostrar el mensaje y luego vuelve a desaparecer.

Es primera vez que me sucede esto, ya he desactivado el cache, incremente la memoria, active el **error_reporting** y nada.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//HEADER PARA PERMITIR PETICIONES DE OTROS DOMINIOS 
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');   
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');   

//DESACTIVAR CACHE  
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

set_time_limit(90);

print "TEST";
exit;
```

¿Tienen alguna idea de que puede ser?
¿Les ha pasado esto?

Comment: En el access.log del servidor te salen todas las peticiones exitosas (200)? En el navegador qué te sale cuando miras las herramientas de desarrollo? Sale siempre que te carga el recurso? Qué sale en los headers de la respuesta?

Comment: @Alfabravo las herramientas de desarrollo estan vacias, no hay nada, igualmente los headers de respuesta. No tengo acceso al access.log del servidor

Comment: Si las herramientas de desarrollo están vacías, entonces tu petición no está llegando a ninguna parte. Por favor, revisa la pestaña Network.

Comment: @Alfabravo Ok disculpa, acabo de verificar y en la pestaña Network hay un error 500 Internal Server Error, ahora la pregunta es como puedo visualizar ese error? tengo activo el error reporting y no muestra nada.

Answer (score 0):

Ya esta resuelto, el problema era con la memoria del servidor, tuve que crear un htaccess con el siguiente código

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
php_value memory_limit 64M
</IfModule>
```